# In Corona SDK, How do I keep a player from being dug into platforms?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a small endless running game in which a player (a small box) moves left and right in between platforms. I noticed that the player is dug into the platforms. I tried tweaking the density on both player physics body and platform physics body. But none of them worked. Is this related to anchorX,anchorY by any chance?

[image]

```
local physics = require('physics')
physics.start()

player = display.newImageRect('boxy.png',30,30)
player.anchorX = 0
player.anchorY = 0
player.x = 200
physics.addBody(player,'dynamic', {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})

platformLeft = display.newRect(100,300,450,30)
platformLeft:setFillColor(0,0,0)
platformLeft.anchorX = 1
platformLeft.anchorY = 0.5
platformLeft.x = (width - 1) * 30
platformLeft.y = _H + 90
physics.addBody(platformLeft,'static', {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
platgroup:insert(platformLeft)

platformRight = display.newRect(100,350,450,30)
platformRight:setFillColor(0,0,0)
platformRight.anchorX = 0
platformRight.anchorY = 0.5
platformRight.x = width * 30
platformRight.y = _H + 90
physics.addBody(platformRight,'static', {density = 1,friction = 0, bounce = 0})
platgroup:insert(platformRight)
```

Comment: you should provide a screenshot of that "dug into the platforms" situation or at least state how far they overlap.

Comment: Uploaded. As you can see almost half of the box is covered.

Comment: If you think it might be related to anchorX and anchorY, did you try to change them and see what happens?  also checkout https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setDrawMode.html for debugging

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a shape to the physics body.

[Corona - Physics - Add Body](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/addBody.html)

And as mentioned above by Piglet, try setting the Physics draw mode to Hybrid, is incredibly useful for debugging.